# Is it possible to use an Sqlite database using NativeScript?

Tags: javascript, android, telerik, nativescript

I wanted to build an application using NativeScript but i did not find if it's possible to use an sqlite database. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for now, but I believe(at least hope) this will be added in the coming months.

https://github.com/NativeScript/cross-platform-modules/issues/191
https://github.com/NativeScript/cross-platform-modules/issues/141

Comment: Thanks to your answer i hope too.

Answer (score 5):

I'm actually working on a sqlite wrapper (at least the Android side currently).   If you are interested in testing or using; the repository will be http://github.com/nathanaela/nativescript-sqlite when I publish it.   I hope to have it working soon.    I will need the apple side also; so that module will be done once I have the android side working.

Update: iOS and Android sides are fully working.  Docs on the github or npmjs.org site explain installation.

Comment: I released it yesterday.  So it should be available on the Android side.   I'm investigating the iphone side right now and see that it is the standard sqlite interface; so once I understand how NativeScript works on the ios platform; I should be able to get the ios side done.

Comment: thanks for your work it's a very good help to me, i needed that a lot, now i can start to learn nativescript.

Comment: Oops, I totally forgot to update this post.  Both the IOS and Android side have been released for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime this might work - https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/

It's a copy of sqlite compiled to javascript with emscripten.